# When I make any comments or post status in Facebook group, my other friends who are not the member of that groups also notified

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

Whenever I make any comments in a Facebook group or do any activity in a particular group, all my friends get notifications for that update, even if they are not part of that group. How can I stop my updates from them?

Answer (score 3):

The group needs to be private (closed or secret), otherwise they publish updates.

Something you can do, which I know isn't ideal, is to delete from your time-line the publication of the group update. Of course, if one of your friends just refreshed his stream before you got a chance to delete it, they might see it but it's better than nothing.

Comment: The group options are open, closed, and secret.  Your posts to open groups are seen by your friends, but not posts to closed or secret groups unless the friend is a group member.  With a secret group your friends won't even see that the group exists.